# Avoid await for each individual loop iteration with Promise.all

Tags: javascript

I would like to change items (f) of an object array (t) during a for loop iteration.
The code show below works fine.

```
for (const f of t) {
  f.value = await getValue(f.a, f.b)
  f.coordinate = 'not empty'
}
```

However, I would like to avoid using the await keyword when calling `getValue` **and instead use Promise.all** or some alternative in order to execute many `getValue` function calls at the same time. Currently each iteration waits for the `getValue` function to be finished before continuing with the next loop iteration.

Without the need of changing the object that is being iterated I would solve it using a `promises` array variable that I push the promises to during each iteration. However, as I'm changing the iterated object array, I'm not sure how to accomplish my goal.

Comment: but wouldn't that just be the same? why do you want to avoid using `await`?

Comment: @fedesc I would like to use await Promise.all at the end after the for loop was executed in order to wait for all getValue calls to be finished. The current loop waits for each individual getValue call to be finished. Therefore it does not run in parallel. At least i think that's the usecase for promise.all - I'm not an expert.

Comment: so in your `for...of` loop just prepare the iterable to call later in await [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: @fedesc: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `for...of` loop just prepare the iterable to call later in await [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```js
let promises = [];
for (const f of t) {
  promises.push(getValue(f.a, f.b))
  f.coordinate = 'not empty'
}
// and then call Promise all with or without async await syntax
Promise.all(promises).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
// or
let result = await Promise.all(promises);
```

i don't know how your promise works (`getValue`) but i'm guessing it's a function that takes in variables and returns a promise - but this is the idea,
prepare the iterable and then call it.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that I want the data (the result of getValue) in f.value like in the example I've shown.

Comment: You would have to bring all the values back with `promise.all` and then iterate it again to put it inside `f.value` . This really complicates things. `for...of` with await is perfectly fine for what you are trying to do. why not just leave it with the await?